# How to get the body of a Docked Composer to vertically scroll?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, scrolling

In the [Docked Composer](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/docked-composer/) blueprint there is no example of how to introduce vertical scrolling (`slds-scrollable_y`) into the body section (`slds-docked-composer__body`). This is needed when the fields displayed in that section exceed the available 355 pixels of height.

I've tried and failed to add `slds-scrollable_y`; is there a clean solution to making this scrolling work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform's inbuilt Docked Composer panels appear to have a hard-coded body height of `379px` to make the scrolling work.

Copying that:

```
/* Platform's UI has this hard-coded value so copy that */
.fixed-body-height {
    height: 379px;
}
```

and:

```
<header class="slds-docked-composer__header slds-grid slds-shrink-none">
    ...
</header>
<div class="slds-docked-composer__body slds-scrollable__y fixed-body-height">
    ...
</div>
<footer class="slds-docked-composer__footer slds-shrink-none">
    ...
</footer>
```

makes the scrolling work.

But if you have a cleaner solution do share it.